# Javascript elements only snapping to grid from right side

Tags: javascript, resize

I am trying to resize elements so that they snap to a grid and so far it is working if I resize from the right side and bottom but for some reason it doesn't work from the left side. I am sure it's just my math but here is the code:

```
var dimension = win.getDimension();
var newW = Math.round(dimension[0] / 10) * 10;
var newH = Math.round(dimension[1] / 10) * 10;
win.setDimension(newW, newH);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was having an event called onBeforeResizeStart which saved the current x position for the window and in the onResizeFinish event I checked to see if the new x position matched the saved x position. If it did not then I just updated the x position and did the same snap calculation.

onBeforeResizeStart:

```
var position = getCoords(win);
window.CurrentX = position.left;
```

onResizeFinish

```
var position = getCoords(win);
if(position.left != window.currentX)
{
    var newX = Math.round(position.left / 10) * 10;
    win.setPosition(newX, position.top);
}

var dimension = win.getDimension();
var newW = Math.round(dimension[0] / 10) * 10;
var newH = Math.round(dimension[1] / 10) * 10;

win.setDimension(newW, newH);
```